# Dynamic Arrangement of Widgets using KIVY

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am a new user to Kivy and
I would like to Dynamically assign widgets according to what data is present in a file. Basically in this case Every line which is multiple of 4 should be a Label while the 3 lines under it should be able to fit in a GridLayout of 1 row and 3 columns.

This is my Unsuccessful attempt at doing so.

```
file = open("wordattack.txt","r")
ct=0
class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    def build(self):
        for line in file:
            f = FloatLayout(text= line, text_size= '32', size_hint= (1,0.3))
            g = GridLayout(rows= 1, cols = 3, col_default_width= 10 )

            if (ct%4==0):

                f.add_widget(g)
            else:
                fl = FloatLayout(text= line, text_size= '32', size_hint= (1,0.3))
                g.add_widget(f1)
            print (line+ ct)
            ct+=1
         return f

class Random(App):

    def build(self):

        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Random().run()
```

I get no output Whatsoever. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first of all, `FloatLayout` *!=* `Label`, therefore no `text` property and so on... but I guess that's only a typo. Then, `text_size` is something else than `font_size`, which is the variable you want(making text bigger/smaller).

That for loop that's your doing, I'll show it in code, the important parts right now:

- `build()` function is function from `App()` class, therefore it works only in `class Random(App)` which is your main class(something like `int main(...)` in other languages and *will not execute* because you didn't call it at all.
- The function(/method) you need is called [`init()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) and that's the one that will execute.
- that `return f` will not work at all the way you want it, because in `Random(App)` the `return RootWidget()` returns the `RootWidget` itself and `return f` will not change the widget's content no matter what, you change it with `add_widget()` and [other functions](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html)
- *`Random`* name is rather non-usable name if you will use something from `random` library, it might and might not collide, so it's safer to avoid that kind of naming your classes

I used `BoxLayout`, because using Float-one would probably put all widgets at one place as you didn't specify positioning and you wouldn't see the output clearly. Also, creating widgets inside of if-else is more efficient than creating it outside of the statement, because this way you create only the thing you want and no random trash will hang out in the memory.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    ct=0
    orientation='vertical'
    file = ['Q1','a','b','c','Q2','d','e','f','Q3','g','h','i',]
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        optct=1
        g = GridLayout(rows=1, cols=3, col_default_width=10)
        for line in self.file:
            if (self.ct%4==0):
                # question here
                f = Label(text=line, font_size=32, size_hint= (1,0.3))
                self.add_widget(f)
            else:
                g.add_widget(Button(text=line))
                if optct%3==0:
                    # add when the last(3/3) option is in the loop
                    self.add_widget(g)
                    # reset the widget
                    g = GridLayout(rows=1, cols=3, col_default_width=10)
                optct+=1
            self.ct+=1

class Random(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()
Random().run()
```

Comment: Code works without any errors but it isn't exactly what I wanted to do.
I am basically trying to display some questions with options underneath. I have the Question on every 4th line (0 included). And the 3 options on the rest of the lines. I would like to create a Label for for the Question and then followed by a vertical GridLayout with 3 Labels with the Options. So the 3 Labels Need to be inside the GridLayout.

Comment: That is pretty much what I wanted to do. Thank you so much.
I have like a zillion more questions regarding positioning of the widgets, alignment, where to apply pos_hint and size_hint, etc, though.
I hope you would be willing to help out. If so is there an easier way we can communicate??

Comment: Sometimes I hang out on [irc](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=kivy), which is the best source for your answers together with [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html) about kivy. Also, there is [tutorial](http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/) which covers even positioning. The best for you is to watch that tutorial(or part of it) and then contact people with questions. :)